# which plugin is used for pay registration fees in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When i am register in site there is a categorywise fees.I want to pay this fees using woocommerce plugin.I dont know how to do this.Please suggest plugin which is good for this?

I have finding many plugin but it was not fullfil my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Please generate product with category name in woo-commerce plugin product page